# Using wildcards in gsub

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to do something like this:

```
"String with text and $abc$ and $def$ and so on... ".gsub("$*$", "replaceText")
```

which results in

```
"String with text and replaceText and replaceText and so on... "
```

But I have no idea how wildcards like `*` work here.

Comment: It is not a wild card. It does not work like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex for this purpose

```
"String with text and $abc$ and $def$ and so on... ".gsub(/\$\w+\$/, "replaceText")
#=> "String with text and replaceText and replaceText and so on... "
```

Remember you will need to escape $

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity: whether one has more delimiters (not the dollar sign only,) she might use [back-references](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Capturing):

```
str = "String with text and $abc$ and *def* and so on... "
str.gsub(/(?<delim>[$*]).*?\k<delim>/, "replaceText")
#⇒ "String with text and replaceText and replaceText and so on... "
```

Note that inside `[]` there is no need to escape `$` (`*` neither.)

Comment: This also works with special caracters like "ä" or "ü"

Comment: I am not sure I understood how it is supposed to be used with letters from some European alphabets, having diacritics.

Answer (score 0):

```
"String with text and $abc$ and $def$ and so on... ".gsub(/\$\w+\$/, "replaceText")
```

Try \$\w+\$ in http://rubular.com/

http://rubular.com/r/ZbgdVQvDGb